# How to automate multiple test cases from TFS in multiple systems using Microsoft Test Manager?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, msdn, mtm

I have 1000 test cases present in TFS. Now I would like to automate those test cases using MTM(Microsoft Test Manager). I would like to download those test cases from TFS and run it in any client machines using MTM. How to achieve this? I followed this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx#link.

Comment: If you have followed that link then please describe your problem? Link described how to associate automations with Test Cases and run them

Comment: Here for every test case we have to map particular test method right. Is there a way I can give the test project location at one place so that all the test cases in TFS can link to that path. So we no need to configure the test methods for each and every test cases.

Comment: You can either create the Test Case first then automate, or create the Automation first and Generate the Test Case. If you are automating in TFS 2015+ there is no need for Test Cases... you can associate Test Results directly to Requriments

Answer (score 1):

You have been able to do this since TFS 2010, and I have described how in the first two options. However if you are using TFS 2015+ (including VSTS) then this method has been deprecated and a new system is being built. See option #3 below for the best way to do this.

Option #3 also includes other tools as part of the new Team Build system to run automated tests from agents on multiple environments. See "Functional Testing Task" for that bit...

#### 1 Associate an Automation with a Test Case (pre 2015)

For this follow the documentation that you have from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx and you need to associate each Automation individually with the Test Cases that it represents.

*note: This only works with Automated Tests built in MSTest*

#### 2 Generate Test Cases for an Automation (pre 2015)

If you don't have the Test Cases first you can use tcm.exe to to generate the Test Cases stubs from an automation assembly. Follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465191.aspx for the docs. I have run this as part of my build process so that it is always up to date.

*note: This only works with Automated Tests built in MSTest*

#### 3 Associate Automation directly with a Requirement (recommended)

If this is for tractability then you can use the new tools in TFS 2015/VSTS to directly associate a Test Result from a build with a Requirement. Once associated all future results will also be associated and there is a nice dashboard widget that displays this nicely.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/08/02/traceability-with-continuous-testing/